# How to invert a lagrangian polynomial

Tags: r, inverse-problem

I'm reading the following [paper](http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2529684) (Grezlak and Oosterlee) and I have a specific question to a sentence on page 5. I quote:

> "Since the mapping $y=g(x)$ is bijective and $g(x)$ is strictly
>   increasing, so is $g^{-1}(y)$. This implies that the arguments $x$ can
>   be obtained by the inverse interpolation of $g(x)$ against $y$, which
>   can be done at essentially no cost."

For given points $x_i,y_i$ they define $g$ to be the lagrange polynomial:

$$g(x) = \sum_{i=1}^Ny_il_i(x)$$
where $l_i(x)=\prod_{j=1,j\not=i}\frac{x-x_j}{x_i-x_j}$. They cite a paper (E. Michalup. On inverse linear interpolation. Scandinavian Actuarial Journal 1950) about this inverse interpolation which is unfortunatelly not available for free. I'm working with R and was browsing the web about inverse linear interpolation and found the following [function](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/NLSstClosestX.html). However, it seems to be quite costly. Even worse it just takes a single numeric value as input (yval), which means I need to call the function as many time as inverse I want to calculate. Is there another way to do it or a better function in R?

Comment: In english wikipedia you can read an improve with barycentric. Other alternative is Hermite polynomial. You can use divided differences. Look for packages in R to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing anything about inverse interpolation, this problem should be a straight-forward numerical task given the information about $g(x)$.

Firstly, $g(x)$ is said to be monotonously increasing.
Therefore, given $y$, find two nodes s.t. $g(x_i)\leq y\leq g(x_{i+1})$ [this is simple since all is ordered].

From there, use any root-finder which should converge rapidly.
This method has the drawback that you have to solve a system for every point $y$.
What you can do to speed it up is to add any evaluated point of $g(x)$ in the root-finding process to the list which will decrease the number of future iterations assuming you start from a low-degree polynomial, i.e., small $N$.